# What's the quota for Document List API requests?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

We're currently integrating Google Drive/Docs access in our mobile Apps and use the Google Document List API for this purpose. Are there any restrictions on the number of requests allowed for single API key?

I can't find any information in the Google API Console as the Document List API is not listed there. I can only activate the Google Drive API (which does not yet support functionalities we need).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Documents List API does not use API keys in the same way as the newer APIs such as Drive. We (Google) do not give exact quota details for this API, but in general the value is extremely high. You may encounter [503 responses which indicate that you should perform exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#implementing_exponential_backoff). If, despite this, you are hitting an absolute ceiling, you should contact us and we will investigate, and look to increase your quota.