# Documents List API authorizes less than 10 requests/second?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am forced to use the Documents List API (and not the Drive SDK) because I need exact info about the ACLs, while the Drive SDK usually only provides the first/last name in the ACL info.

I am processing more than 1 million docs for which I need the ACLs. However, I discovered that when I try to perform more than 10 requests/second, I get "Request rate limit exceeded" errors from the Documents List API.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385273/whats-the-quota-for-document-list-api-requests) makes me think that the quota is supposed to be much bigger, can anyone confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to double check in google apis that you have set it up to 10 requests a second by default its set lower then that.  The Max you can set it to is 10 requests a second there is nothing you can do to change that. Its probably to prevent you from flooding the server.

If you do encounter the error you can Implementing exponential backoff and then try again after the alloted time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try batching as described here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#batching_resource_operations_into_a_single_request

My experience when using the Drive SDK equivalent wasn't great, ie. I got "rate limit exceeded" at the same rate as with individual requests. However since you're using the older API, you might have more luck.

Comment: Hey pinoyyid, I did not find a way to batch ACL requests from various documents in the Documents List API. I can either batch document query requests across documents or batch acl requests on only 1 doc. Did you manage to batch ACL requests across multiple docs ?

Comment: disclaimer: I've done nothing with either ACLs or Docslist batching. Reading the link I pasted above, I interpret that as a way to batch any arbitrary docslist calls. That's certainly the way it operates under the Drive API, and generally the docslist API is more capable than Drive.

Comment: Thanks for the disclaimer. But I confirm you it won't work, I tested on the OAuth Playground :-)

Comment: I didn't realise the OAuth Playground supported docslist so I've learned something :-)